# Get data from child component in react in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, ecmascript-2016

I have a base component whose render function looks like this

```
    <QuestionsDrawer open={this.state.drawerOpen} onClose={this._toggleDrawer}>
      <Search />
      <QuestionList
        questions={this.state.rowData}
        selected={[]}
        ref={ref => (this.listItem = ref)}
      />
    </QuestionsDrawer>
```

When the drawer is closed the `this._toggleDrawer` function is called.

```
_toggleDrawer = () => {
  console.log("selected", this.listItem._fetchSelected());
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    drawerOpen: !prevState.drawerOpen,
  }));
};
```

When this happens I would like to get the data from the `QuestionList` component. I have tried `refs` but I am getting a `Cannot read property '_fetchSelected' of undefined` error.

This is what the function in the `QuestionList` component looks like

```
_fetchSelected = () => {
  return this.state.selected;
};
```

What's going wrong here and is there a better way of implementing this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in the Parent component and pass that down by props to the child component. This method can take an argument where you send in `this.state.selected` from your child component. Your parent component will then get access to this data from the method.

I've made a quick visualization of code below and hope you get the idea.

```
// Callback function in the parent that gets passed
// by props to QuestionList

const questionListCallback = (dataFromQuestionList) => {
  // Do something with the data from QuestionList here
}

<QuestionsDrawer open={this.state.drawerOpen} onClose={this._toggleDrawer}>
  <Search />
  <QuestionList
    questions={this.state.rowData}
    drawerOpen={this.state.drawerOpen}
    callbackFromParent={this.questionListCallback}
    selected={[]}
    ref={ref => (this.listItem = ref)}
  />
</QuestionsDrawer>


// Below is for the QuestionList component
// If you for example want to grab the data in componentDidUpdate

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // Do something to get the data here and store it somewhere
  // Maybe in the state in the child?
  if (!this.props.drawerOpen && prevState.data !== this.state.data) {
    this.setState({ data: data}, () =>{
      callbackFromParent(data);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me an example of how I could achieve something like that since this isn't a tradition parent child relation, it's more of parent children and I need the child callback to fire when a parent callback comes through.

Comment: Ok. Then maybe I misunderstood cause it seemed like a traditional pattern. =) If you have som flag or something .. maybe something in your state that changes when the parent callback come through it will automatically rerender the child components. Then the callback that is sent to the child will also fire. 
I always have one parent component in my code that have the state and methods that I send down to the children when the parent have done som fetching or anything else that should trigger a change.

Comment: I've edit my answer now ... have to go now sorry so it was a quick one!